# Form Submission does not work in Internet Explorer - Joomla

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, joomla

I have seen some similar questions to mine , but most of them have some code related issue that prevents them from work... In my vase the form submit works well in safari, chrome , firefox
But in the internet explorer version i click the `submit button` and it doesn't do anything.
Initially i thought it might be a networking problem , or maybe an html problem ? But it doesn't make sense to detect a click and not do the action.

What could possible be the problem ? since the difference between browsers is basically the way they read the html right ?

I'm interested in learning more about this issue !

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: What version of IE? IE 10- is not supported by Joomla's jQuery library that handles validation on form submits. You should check console warnings and give more details what form you have troubles with.

Comment: i used IE 10 and 11 for testing!

Comment: But the form validations are not made through jquery, i used the custom code that my company uses... The problem mightbe in the button click ..

Comment: If you use custom code, noone can help you unless you show the custom code. My suggestion would be to try Edge, if that works, ditch outdated Browsers all together.

Comment: Fixed it by changing the button to a input type submit...weird but it worked

Comment: You could post your solution as an answer and mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem by changing the `<button> </button>` tag to an `<input type="submit">`
maybe that's not a propper solution but it worked for me !!

Hope it helps someone!!