# JOOMLA - Login form Error message in Internet Explorer

Tags: forms, authentication, internet-explorer, joomla

I am using a Joomla extension to do a login form, it works really well on chrome, safari etc..

But in IE i am running into several issues:

Ex: [Form Submission does not work in Internet Explorer - Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840795/form-submission-does-not-work-in-internet-explorer-joomla)  (fixed)

But now the same forms aren't displaying the error messages if u fill them the wrong way 
I don't understand if it is a compatibility problem with IE or not ...

Comment: I suggest you clear the cache for the site and again try to test a similar issue with the IE browser. I also suggest you post a sample code and steps to run it. So that we can try to check and test the code to find the cause of the issue. Without code, it is hard to tell why it is not showing any validation messages. There is an official Joomla forum. https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=516738 You can also try to post the question there to know their opinion.

Comment: Already did it .. i detected the error using the lambda test tool, will further investigate the issue. I know without code it's a bit hard, but i was just asking trying to just get an opinion on the issue. Thanks!

Comment: It is better to ask to Joomla forum as they can give some hint about their product.